# Invalid content was found starting with element metamug

Tags: xml, rest, metamug

I'm getting the following error, when trying to save the resource file

```
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0":update}'. One of '{"http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0":Desc, "http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0":Param, "http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0":Execute, "http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0":Query, "http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0":Update}' is expected.
```

This is the resource file, I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
    <Request method="POST">
        <Desc> CRICKET INFO </Desc>
        <update>
          insert into CRICKET (NAME,DOB,BATTING_STYLE,BOWLING_STYLE,TEAMS)
          values($xname,$dob,$batstyle,$bowlstyle,$comment); 
      </update>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update` tag needs to be in Title case. In fact all the tags in metamug resource file are upper cased. So make it `Update` and it will work file. That's what the error is also pointing at.

The xml is being validated against the xsd schema that can be found [here](http://xml.metamug.net/schema/resource.xsd).

If you use a schema aware editor (e.g Eclipse, Netbeans ). It will help you auto complete the xml tags and attribute and provide in-place validation.

```
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0 http://xml.metamug.net/schema/resource.xsd" 
 v="1.0">
    <Request method="POST">
        <Desc> CRICKET INFO </Desc>
        <Update>
          insert into CRICKET (NAME,DOB,BATTING_STYLE,BOWLING_STYLE,TEAMS)
          values($xname,$dob,$batstyle,$bowlstyle,$comment); 
      </Update>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```